# MATLAB: Storing values in a structure

Tags: matlab, for-loop, field, matlab-struct

Good day MATLAB pros,

I have a long list of (single value) variables in my workspace that has to be stored into an array for every loop of execution.

Here's a simple example:
Variables in the workspace:

```
a = 1;
b = 2.2;
c = 3.4;
d = [0.5 0.7 1 1.2 1.5];
e = [-15 -10 -5 0 5 10 15 20];
serial = {'WTZ00151'};
model = {'336F'};

NameList = {'a';'serial';'model'};
```

1) Here, I'm saving only the single value variables into `Data` structure, however what I'd like to do is for every loop, save the single values into an array in `Data` structure.

```
varList = who;
Data = struct;

fields = fieldnames(Data, '-full');
fieldSizes = structfun(@(field) length(field),Data);

% removing arrays from structure
for lst = 1:length(fieldSizes)
    if fieldSizes(lst) > 1
        Data = rmfield(Data,fields(lst));
    end
end

Data = 

      Data: [1x1 struct]
         a: 1
         b: 2.2000
         c: 3.4000
     index: 10
     model: {'336F'}
    serial: {'WTZ00151'}
```

So if I run this in a loop, `for i = 1:5`, `Data` should look like this:

```
Data = 

      Data: [1x1 struct]
         a: [1 1 1 1 1]
         b: [1x5 double]
         c: [1x5 double]
     index: [10 10 10 10 10]
     model: {1x5 cell}
    serial: {1x5 cell}
```

Any ideas on how to code the `for` loop?

2) Since there are too many variables in the workspace & I have a long list of variables that needs storing, instead of using `who` to save ALL variables to the structure (and then filtering out the unwanted), how could I use a list of variable names (imported from a text file: `NameList`) to call out what needs to be stored? Using the variable name from NameList does not call out the structure values.

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not immediately clear what part of your code actually is creating your data structure. There are several ways to create a `struct` from your array of variable names.

One way is to save the relevant variables to a file and load them back into a `struct`

```
save('tmp.mat', NameList{:});
Data = load('tmp.mat');
```

Another option (not recommended) is to use `eval`

```
for k = 1:numel(NameList)
    Data.(NameList{k}) = eval(NameList{k});
end
```

As far as storing data from multiple iterations, I personally would recommend storing the data into an *array of `struct`* rather than a `struct` of arrays. You should be able to store each `Data` instance in an array using `k` as an index as shown below:

```
allData(k) = Data;
```

If you decide you really want a `struct` of arrays, you can always convert it afterwards.

```
fields = fieldnames(allData);

output = struct();

for k = 1:numel(fields)
    % Try to just concatenate the values together
    try
        values = [allData.(fields{k})];

    % If that failed, concatenate them within a cell array
    catch
        values = {allData.(fields{k})};
    end

    % Store this in a single output struct
    output.(fields{k}) = values;
end
```

Comment: Excellent response. Thank you very much for your help.